# Make The Dock And Menu Bar Appear Quickly In Full Screen Mode?

Tags: terminal, fullscreen, dock

I have run commands in terminal to make my dock re-appear quicker than default so now it re-appears instantly. In full-screen mode, it doesn't appear quickly like non-full screen mode does.

How can I make the behaviour of the dock in full-screen mode the same as if it were in non-full-screen mode?

Also, is it possible to make the menubar appear instantly in full-screen mode like the dock?

Comment: Is this MAc OSX?

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan It is for MacOS. I thought this forum was only for MacOS

Comment: StackExchange has a number of related sites. You probably were thinking of `Ask Different` (https://apple.stackexchange.com/), which is geared towards Apple products only. [Super User is a bit broader than that](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry for the mistake. This shall be migrated.